# Google extension Check My Links returns different test results for the same webpage

Tags: manual-testing, web, chrome, web-testing

I am using `Check My Links` to verify if a webpage has any deadlink, but interestingly, for the same given page, Check My Links returns a few different test results. One result is **183** while another one is **221**. The only difference is:

- **For test result returned as 221, a tab was expanded while for 183, there was no expanded tab.**

Anyone knows why this happens?

FYI: Check My Links is a free Google Chrome Extension tool that crawls a webpage and looks for dead links.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some webpages display elements based on viewport size of the browser. I have used CheckMyLinks XPI with chromedriver in a test Automation suite in the past and it provided consistent results.

Please ensure you use same viewport size and check for consistency of results or follow the below approach to verify if viewport size impacts number of links on the page:

- Open the webpage and go to browser console
- type `$x("//*[contains(@href,'http')]")` and hit return

Observe the number of elements it returns. Use same approach for a different viewport size.

Note: If the href's on the page use relative links, you may modify the xpath accordingly